# Overloading logging methods in Log4J

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I create logger in my code ussing following line:

```
public final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
```

I do logging like:

```
log.info("blablabla");
```

Now I need to expand my logging functionallity by adding logging to custom server if required:

```
log.info("blabla", true);
```

Overloaded methot should look like:

```
info ( String msg, Boolean logToSrv)
{
if logToSrv { sendInfoTosrv(msg) };
info(msg);
}
```

What is the best approach to solve my problem?

My appenders in my log4j.properies file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL,console, f

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%-10t] %-5p %30c %60l  -  %m%n


log4j.appender.f=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.f.File=f.log
log4j.appender.f.Threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.f.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x  - %m%n
log4j.appender.f.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%-10t] %-5p %30c %60l  -  %m%n
log4j.appender.f.Append=false
```

Comment: What about create a wrapper class?

Comment: Why can't you just add another appender?

Comment: I have no experience with creating appenders, but as far I understood I need create appender class and overload info method?

Comment: You have appenders specified in your config, that's all there is to it. There are a lot of appenders already existing, should be rare to need to create one.

Comment: What do you mean by "There are a lot of appenders already existing". I need appender that does my job parallel to logging and has additional parameter in logging functions.